# Translate letter(char) index in integer index POI Java

Tags: java, apache-poi

How do I translate excel cell index  AA to 26 , AB to 27? Is there a way for Apache POI to use Column index in letter and translate it into its integer representation?

To get integer value of index if i pass "AA" as a parameter to input function and it will return 26.

Comment: Unless you mean AA = 27, AB = 28 and so on

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apache POI has this built in, just use [CellReference.convertColStringToIndex](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellReference.html#convertColStringToIndex-java.lang.String-)

> `public static int convertColStringToIndex(java.lang.String ref)`
>
> takes in a column reference portion of a CellRef and converts it from ALPHA-26 number format to 0-based base 10. 'A' -> 0 'Z' -> 25 'AA' -> 26 'IV' -> 255

Comment: Thank you it helped me. Saved my day.